# Failing when running celery from docker

Tags: django, docker, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to get celery to work with Django and docker and the building works well but I celery won't run. Any ideas?

Here is are the `docker-compose logs -f` errors

```
Starting django-celery_redis_1 ... done
Starting django-celery_db_1    ... done
Starting django-celery_flower_1        ... done
Starting django-celery_celery_beat_1   ... done
Starting django-celery_celery_worker_1 ... done
Starting django-celery_web_1           ... done
Attaching to django-celery_db_1, django-celery_redis_1, django-celery_celery_worker_1, django-celery_flower_1, django-celery_celery_beat_1, django-celery_web_1
celery_beat_1    | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
db_1             | 2021-03-28 18:18:15.611 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 8.3.0) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1             | 2021-03-28 18:18:15.613 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1             | 2021-03-28 18:18:15.616 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
celery_worker_1  | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
db_1             | 2021-03-28 18:18:15.648 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
redis_1          | 1:C 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.425 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1          | 1:C 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.425 # Redis version=5.0.12, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1          | 1:C 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.425 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis_1          | 1:M 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.427 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1          | 1:M 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.427 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
redis_1          | 1:M 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.427 # Server initialized
redis_1          | 1:M 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.427 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
redis_1          | 1:M 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.428 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
redis_1          | 1:M 28 Mar 2021 18:18:15.428 * Ready to accept connections
flower_1         | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
web_1            | standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
db_1             | 2021-03-28 18:18:15.777 UTC [19] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-03-28 18:16:52 UTC
db_1             | 2021-03-28 18:18:15.791 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
django-celery_celery_worker_1 exited with code 1
django-celery_flower_1 exited with code 1
django-celery_celery_beat_1 exited with code 1
django-celery_web_1 exited with code 1
```

UPDATED: added docker-compose.yml file for better references on the stack problem. The build succeeds but when running `docker-compose up` it doesn't and throws the celery error

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: django_celery_example_web
    # '/start' is the shell script used to run the service
    command: /start
    # this volume is used to map the files and folders on the host to the container
    # so if we change code on the host, code in the docker container will also be changed
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8010:8000
    # env_file is used to manage the env variables of our project
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=hello_django_dev
      - POSTGRES_USER=hello_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello_django

  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine

  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: django_celery_example_celery_worker
    command: /start-celeryworker
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  celery_beat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: django_celery_example_celery_beat
    command: /start-celerybeat
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.dev-sample
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  flower:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: django_celery_example_celey_flower
    command: /start-flower
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env/.dev-sample
    ports:
      - 5557:5555
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: can u share your docker-compose.yaml file?

Comment: @ItayB Done! Is there a need of the `Dockerfile` and the setup structure aswell?

Comment: more important is the content of `start-celeryworker`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it applies to your case, but in docker i start celery with this command:

```
command: celery -A my_proj worker -l DEBUG
```

Since the error it gives you is "exec format error" it might just be this.